# the fetched data from documentum (dm_acl Object Table) turns out to be null ? why?

Tags: dql, documentum, dfc

I'm working on a Java project which is connected to documentum . I am trying to fetch some data from my dm_acl object table using the following :

```
String fetchAclsInfoQuery = "select * from dm_acl where description = '@aclname0' or description = '@aclname1' or description = '@aclname2' enable (ROW_BASED) ";
            fetchAclsInfoQuery = fetchAclsInfoQuery.replace("@aclname0", list.get(0));
            fetchAclsInfoQuery = fetchAclsInfoQuery.replace("@aclname1", newAcl1.toString().toLowerCase());
            fetchAclsInfoQuery = fetchAclsInfoQuery.replace("@aclname2", newAcl2.toString().toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(fetchAclsInfoQuery);

//The problem starts from here  ==> 
            IDfQuery aclDetailsFetching = new DfQuery();
            //IDfCollection col = UpdateQuery.execute(_session, IDfQuery.DF_QUERY);
            IDfCollection details = aclDetailsFetching.execute(_session, DfQuery.DF_READ_QUERY);
            while(details.next()){
                System.out.println(details.getString("owner_name"));
            }
```

once I print out the results of "fetchAclsInfoQuery" and run it in DQL tester it works perfectly fine how ever when I try to out put the values stored in "owner_name" column all I get is null .
Any idea where my mistake is ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set DQL statement to query object.
add `aclDetailsFetching.setDQL(fetchAclsInfoQuery);`

Answer (score 0):

Try writing

```
String fetchAclsInfoQuery = "select owner_name from dm_acl where description = '@aclname0' or description = '@aclname1' or description = '@aclname2' enable (ROW_BASED) ";
```

instead of

```
String fetchAclsInfoQuery = "select * from dm_acl where description = '@aclname0' or description = '@aclname1' or description = '@aclname2' enable (ROW_BASED) ";
```

I'm quite sure there is a problem with asterisk instead of real property name. 
You can use method `hasAttr("<attribute_name>")` to check wether your desired property (attribute) is loaded in collection.

Comment: They both work well . Just out of curiosity why would you think I need to specify the column names ? ;)

Comment: Because with asterisk you are not specifying property, it may happen that he doesn't put everything in your collection in VM.